# How to open heic format of photos in UWP app

Tags: uwp

I need to open heic format of photo in an UWP app. And the default Image control cannot open it. I tried the third party package ImageEx which comes from NuGet, but also failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to open heic format of photos in UWP app

Derive from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/mt846532(v=vs.85)), The WIC decoding API could decoding heic type, that means you could get `BitmapDecoder` with heic file stream then call `GetSoftwareBitmapAsync` method to convert `SoftwareBitmap`. I have made code sample below that you could use directly.

**Please note** *you need to install HEVC Extension from store before calling the following code. Otherwise, it will throw exception when invoke `GetSoftwareBitmapAsync` method*.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".heic");
    StorageFile inputFile = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (inputFile != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var inputStream = await inputFile.OpenReadAsync();
            var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);
            if (decoder.DecoderInformation.CodecId.Equals(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.JpegDecoderId))
            {

                return;
            }
            var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

            if (softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8 ||
                  softwareBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode == BitmapAlphaMode.Straight)
            {
                softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
            }

            var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
            await source.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap);
            MyImage.Source = source;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;

    }

}
```